Vintage photo, Seatac airport
I’m spending the night in a hotel at Seatac Airport in Seattle, Washington, USA. The vintage photo below is hanging on the wall of my room. I recognize the airport as Seatac, circa 1950’s. The photo appears to depict some sort of celebration, with all of the bunting and crowds.  I initially thought that it might be a Boeing-related airshow, given the company's Seattle roots.  Plus, the aircraft in the upper-left appears to be a B-17, with a 377 in the upper-right.  But the aircraft next to the B-17 appears to be a Fairchild C-119, which seems to eliminate the Boeing connection.  I'm unable to identify the other aircraft.
I'd like help identifying the aircraft in the photo.  Bragging rights awarded to anyone who can id the actual event.

For context, here's the full image:


The photo was taken on July 9 1949, and depicts the opening of Seattle-Tacoma International Airport by governor Arthur Langlie.

The airport cost $11 milliion and opened free of debt. United
Airlines, Northwest Airlines, Pan American World Airways and Western
Airlines started their regular passenger service at Sea-Tac on the day
of the dedication.
This July 1949 aerial photo shows the passenger terminal on the
airport's opening day. Port of Seattle officials estimated that 30,000
people attended the opening to tour the new airport and inspect
several planes. source

All four airlines are shown in the photo:

The two aircraft nearest the camera are -

N88951 Douglas DC-4 in the colours of Pan American World Airways
N47603 Boeing 377 Stratocruiser in the colours of North West Airlines

To the rear on the right is N88816 Douglas DC-4 from Western Airlines; here the same day -
 source
To the rear on the left is a N37540 Douglas DC-6B owned by United Airlines.


source
The two military aircraft at the rear of the picture are proving far less popular with the crowd than the civil ones! They are a Boeing B-17 and a Fairchild C-82 Packet . The USAF was operating Packets out of nearby McChord Field, which might explain its presence. In fact, you can still see a Packet there today.


Bragging rights well deserved! +1
